# Roll back to older build of WIndows 10 Insider Preview on phone

Tags: windows, build, preview

Last night my test device automatically installed the newest build of the Windows 10 Insider Preview, which resulted in the phone not getting recognized by any PC, so I want to know if there's a way to roll back and install an older version or something similar?

Comment: It doesn't appear this is possible. I had a similar issue with an update breaking Visual Studio from deploying projects to the phone. Its ridiculous! One thing you could try is plug the phone in, open devices and printers from control panel. Then unplug your phone. right click on the Windows phone icon and select 'Remove Device' Its worth a shot to re-install the drivers. I have also heard that turning airplane mode on before plugging it in can aid the issue

Comment: Well, that sucks :/ The thing is that the device manager doesn't show it as a Windows Phone device and so I can't even find it and uninstall it in there. But I will try your other suggestions. I sure hope they fix it with the next build.

Comment: Fingers crossed, Admitted they are beta and intended to be buggy but this is quite a problem, especially for people are developing on these devices!